# ASP.NET GridView Column Remove

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` with some predefined `Column`s and some generated in code. The idea is that I show `Column`s according to category, selected by user. I cannot create all `Column`s and just hide them because I don't know how many `Column`s I will need. I manage to generate `Column`s I needed, but the problem starts when I try to remove generated `Column`s. Situation looks like this:

1. On first load I see `GridView` of all categories.
2. After clicking in `ListBox` I get result I want. 1 additional `Column` is created (`RemoveAt` is not called, because no additional `Column`s were yet created.).
3. After clicking in other `ListBox` `Item` I still get result I want. `Column` created last time where deleted and new `Column` added.
4. At this point, if I click any other `ListBox` `Item` in `LicensesCategoriesListBox_SelectedIndexChanged` on debugging I see that all of `GridView` `TemplateField`s are empty (http://tinypic.com/r/98vdkm/8).

If I comment section `gridView.Columns.RemoveAt(i - 1)` everything works fine, just `Column`s keeps generating and generating. Any ideas why all of my `TemplateField`s, written in my `Page` becomes empty?

My `Page` looks like this:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="licensesCategoriesListBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="LicensesCategoriesListBox_SelectedIndexChanged" />
<asp:GridView ID="licencesGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Caption="Licencijos" DataKeyNames="id" ShowFooter="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pavadinimas">
             <EditItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="licenceNameTextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>' />
             </EditItemTemplate>
             <FooterTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="newLicenceNameTextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="50" ToolTip="Pavadinimas" />
             </FooterTemplate>
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <span><%# Eval("name") %></span>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Kategorija">
              <EditItemTemplate>
                  <asp:DropDownList ID="licenceCategoryDropDownList" runat="server" />
              </EditItemTemplate>
              <FooterTemplate>
                  <asp:DropDownList ID="newLicenceCategoryDropDownList" runat="server" ToolTip="Kategorija">
                      <asp:ListItem Text="Pasirinkite kategoriją:" />
                  </asp:DropDownList>
              </FooterTemplate>
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <span><%# Eval("category") %></span>
              </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        FillLicences(ref licencesGridView);
    }
}

protected void LicensesCategoriesListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    FillLicences(ref licencesGridView, licensesCategoriesListBox.SelectedValue); /// Value is ID of category.
}

public void FillLicences(ref GridView gridView, string category = "") {
    DataTable dataTable;
    ushort categoryId;
    if (UInt16.TryParse(category, out categoryId)) {
        PutAdditionalColumns(ref gridView, categoryId);
        dataTable = sqlCommands.GetLicences(categoryId); /// Returns DataTable [name], [category] and additional fields that I add in PutAdditionalColumns method.
    } else {
        dataTable = sqlCommands.GetAllLicences(); /// Returns DataTable with only [name], [category]
    }
    gridView.DataSource = dataTable;
    gridView.DataBind();
}

public void PutAdditionalColumns(ref GridView gridView, uint category) {
    for (ushort i = (ushort)gridView.Columns.Count; i > 2; i--) { /// Removes columns at the end (created for other category)
        gridView.Columns.RemoveAt(i - 1);
    }
    foreach (var pair in sqlCommands.GetLicencesCategoryAttributes(category)) { /// Takes additional field needed.
        TemplateField field = new TemplateField(); /// New empty column.
        field.AccessibleHeaderText = pair.Key.ToString();
        field.HeaderText = pair.Value;
        gridView.Columns.Add(field);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas why all of my TemplateFields, written in my Page becomes
>   empty?

Because each of those fields is considered a Column. You're removing them in the code.

If this is your issue, you need some way to seperate columns defined in the aspx to the ones created in the code.

I'd use `DataColumn.ExtendedProperties` to do this.

Whenever you add a column from code, add a value to ExtendedProperties, showing that it was created in the code.

```
//...
TemplateField field = new TemplateField(); /// New empty column.
field.AccessibleHeaderText = pair.Key.ToString();
field.HeaderText = pair.Value;
DataColumn ourNewColumn = gridView.Columns.Add(field);
ourNewColumn.ExtendedProperties.Add("CreatedInCode", true);
//...
```

And then when you come to delete them, only delete them if they have this property set.

```
//...
if( gridView.Columns[i - 1].ExtendedProperties.ContainsKey("CreatedInCode") ) {
    gridView.Columns.RemoveAt(i - 1);
}
//...
```

Comment: I remove Columns after my first two (for(ushort i=(ushort)gridView.Columns.Count; **i>2** ;i--){gridView.Columns.RemoveAt(i-1);}. Why first `Columns` gets deleted then?

Comment: Ah. Then this isn't the answer you're looking for. Have you checked they're being stored in the correct order when you add/remove them? I see in the screenshot that there's a column at index 0 that shouldnt be there?

Comment: Ups, that's my mistake. Updated picture. I hade additional `Column` with edit button at the beginning of table, but removed it that `Page` file would look cleaner.